# IIS shows me an alert box of Login credential username and password

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to authorize my GET calls in web api, it is working fine( when projects runs on the browser token authenticate properly ) where i published same project in IIS, every time I got a alert box of user name and password. How could i disable this alert box.  what credential he is asking for authenticate. I gave all the registered user name and password from my database. I am confused , help me

Answer (score 0):

Check what type of authentication has been enabled for the site in IIS.I believe you are using Basic authentication type.By default, Basic authentication requires the Windows user account to have local logon rights at the Web server. If you want to disable select the particular website and change the authentication type to Anonymous.

Comment: if I changed authorize to AllowAnonmous then how what would be the purpose of [Authorize] attribute.?? Suggest me what i do in IIS settings to let me allow, as the same in simple running my application.